# SSRS - using a macro, or exporting a chart

Tags: excel, vba, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I've created an SSRS report which the client now wants in Excel, with a chart which reflects the data in it (so if they delete a row in Excel, the chart updates).

Unfortunately, when SSRS exports, the chart is rendered as an image, independent of the data in Excel.

Is there any way around this? Alternatively, is there any way to embed a function in SSRS where the user can trigger a macro (or something similar) which would create the data in Excel for them?

Comment: There is no magic trick to make this work like you want with an SSRS report. You should consider creating this report in PowerPivot if this is the type if functionality you need.

Comment: With PowerPivot, I take it that I would have to create the Excel file (with PowerPivot extensions, so it more or less "hooks in" to the database), then click an update button or something to update it with the latest info?

Comment: That sums it up nicely, yes. If you happen to host your SSRS reports on SharePoint, you can put the Excel file there, and have it do regularly schedule refreshes, too.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've just been told that the client would like to edit information live in the report and have it feed straight back to the db. So I'm working on a different solution. I think they're now going for the report in SSRS, with the ability to filter quite a lot, and the ability to click a record which will take them straight to the editor for it. That should pacify them a bit.